# Why total Budget is not getting updated?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Can someone please check my code in the codePen?
After adding the item to the list, It should log the total budget in the console.

It is only showing 0. Please see the code in the codePen console.
https://codepen.io/crazydeveloper/pen/KbKvMp

```
budCalc: function() {
var budget, percent, totalInc, totalExp;

totalInc = data.totals.inc;
totalExp = data.totals.exp;

budget = data.totals.inc - data.totals.exp;
percent = (data.totals.exp / data.totals.inc)*100
console.log(budget);


///////// BUDGET CONTROLLER ////////
var budgetController = (function() {

var Expence = function(id, des, value) {
this.id = id;
this.des = des;
this.value = value;
}

var Income = function(id, des, value) {
this.id = id;
this.des = des;
this.value = value;
}

var data = {
allItems: {
    inc: [],
    exp: []
},

totals: {
    inc: 0,
    exp: 0,
    budget: 0,
    percent: 0
}

}

return {
addItem: function(type, des, val) {
    var newItem, id;

    if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
        var id = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 
1;
    } else {
        id = 0;
    }

    if (type === "exp") {
        newItem = new Expence(id, des, val);
    } else if (type === "inc") {
        newItem = new Income(id, des, val);
    }

    data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
    return newItem;
},

calcTotal: function(type) {
    sum = 0;
    data.allItems[type].forEach(function() {
        sum += data.totals[type];
        data.totals[type] = data.totals[type] + sum;
    }
)
},

budCalc: function() {
var budget, percent, totalInc, totalExp;

totalInc = data.totals.inc;
totalExp = data.totals.exp;

budget = data.totals.inc - data.totals.exp;
percent = (data.totals.exp / data.totals.inc)*100
console.log(budget);

var getBudget = function() {
    return {
        totalInc: totalInc,
        totalExp: totalExp,
        totalBudget: budget,
        percent: percent
    }
}
},
    testing: function() {
    console.log(data);
}
}
}());




////////// UI CONTROLLER //////////////
var UIController = (function() {
var DOMs = {
inpType: ".add__type",
inpDes: ".add__description",
inpVal: ".add__value",
inpBtn: ".add__btn",
incCon: ".income__list",
expCon: ".expenses__list"
}
return {
    getInp: function() {
        return {
            type: $(DOMs.inpType).val(),
            des: $(DOMs.inpDes).val(),
            val: parseFloat($(DOMs.inpVal).val())
        }
    },

    addListItem: function(obj, type) {
        var html, newHTML, ele;

        if(type === "inc") {
            ele = DOMs.incCon;
            html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="income-%id%"><div 
class="item__description">%des%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div 
class="item__value">+ %val%</div><div class="item__delete"><button 
class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button> 
</div></div></div>';
        } else if(type === "exp") {
            ele = DOMs.expCon;
            html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="expense-%id%"><div 
class="item__description">%des%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div 
class="item__value">- %val%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div> 
<div 
class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios- 
close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
        }

        newHTML = html.replace("%id%", obj.id);
        newHTML = newHTML.replace("%des%", obj.des);
        newHTML = newHTML.replace("%val%", obj.value);

        $(ele).append(newHTML);

        this.clearFields();

    },

    clearFields: function() {
        $(DOMs.inpDes).add(DOMs.inpVal).val("");
        $(DOMs.inpDes).focus();
    },

    getDOM: function() {
        return DOMs;
    }
    }
}
());


////////// MAIN CONTROLLER /////////
var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {

var eventLis = function() {
    var DOM = UICtrl.getDOM();
    $(DOM.inpBtn).on("click", eventBtn);

    $("html").on("keypress", function() {
    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which == 13) {
    eventBtn();
    }
})
}

function eventBtn() {
var input = UICtrl.getInp();

if(input.des !== "" && !isNaN(input.val) && input.val > 0) {
    var newItem = budgetCtrl.addItem(input.type, input.des, input.val);
    UICtrl.addListItem(newItem, input.type);
}
budgetCtrl.budCalc();
}

return {
    init: function() {
        console.log("Application started!");
        eventLis();
    }
}

})(budgetController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

This is all JavaScript code. But I can's figure out why my budget is not updating?

Comment: You need to show enough code in the question for us to see, reproduce, understand and correct the problem you're describing. Please see the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines, and then [edit] your question in order that we can help you. Don't expect us to go to external sites in order to do so.

Comment: Please see codePen https://codepen.io/crazydeveloper/pen/KbKvMp

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 0):

If you check the full data structure object at this point

```
budCalc: function() {
var budget, percent, totalInc, totalExp;

//here
console.log(data);

totalInc = data.totals.inc;
totalExp = data.totals.exp;

budget = data.totals.inc - data.totals.exp;
percent = (data.totals.exp / data.totals.inc)*100
}
```

You will see that data.total attributes are setted to zero everytime

Comment: How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Depending about what you want, here the value is setted to zero and never modified, you need to do it in the calcTotal function() ?